# Add spaces between words in codeigniter label?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a label, created using code igniter. I want 4 spaces between the 2 words in the label. How can I do so?

```
echo form_label('My name', 'namelabel');
```

I tried the following due to [this](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#nbs) but it didn't work:

```
echo form_label('My nbs(4) name', 'namelabel');
```

Comment: try to concatenate to invoke that function as well `echo form_label('My '.nbs(4).' name', 'namelabel');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
echo form_label('My '.nbs(4).' name', 'namelabel');
```

Answer (score -1):

echo form_label('My '.str_repeat(' ', 4);.' name', 'namelabel');